# OroPlatform: how to override datetimepicker js widget

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

## Context

I have a datetime attribute on an entity on my OroPlatform project. It is displayed correctly in the form:

[image]

## Issue

Let's imagine the current time is 7pm.
If I click on the "Today" button, the time field is filled with 7pm20 value instead of 7pm.

I have found that it came from the method `getDefaultTime` in the `public/bundles/oroui/js/app/views/datepicker/datetimepicker-view-mixin.js` file.

So, if I change the method in the original file and run the command `symfony console oro:assets:build` it works as expected.

But I can't find in the Oro documentation the proper way to "override" a method of a js component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a JavaScript module using the `map` section of jsmodules.yml configuration file. E.g.:

```yaml
map:
    '*':
        'jquery': 'oroui/js/jquery-extend'
    'oroui/js/jquery-extend':
        'jquery': 'jquery'
```

For more details see the official documentation: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/configuration/yaml/jsmodules/#map